# Scheme (Racket) if within cond returns nothing

Tags: if-statement, scheme, racket

I have been working in DrRacket, trying to create a "prefix" function (#lang racket).  It should take two lists as an input, and should output `#t` if `pf` is either null, or is equal to the beginning of `ls`.

My problem is that my code doesn't seem to return anything at all when `pf` is not a prefix of `ls` and `ls` isn't null.  If I replace the `#f` in the if statement with something else, like `'()`, it will return that properly, but if I try to capture the `'()` and give an output based on that instead, it gives results that don't make sense (like saying that `'()` isn't null, or that `'()` doesn't equal `'()`).  It seems to have something to do with having an if statement within a cond statement.  Could anyone tell me what it's doing, or why?  Is it possible to make this code work correctly, or am I going to need to rework it another way?

Thanks for the help!

```
(define prefix
  (lambda (pf ls)
    (cond
      [(null? pf) #t]
      [(null? ls) #f]
      [(if (equal? (car pf) (car ls)) (prefix (cdr pf) (cdr ls)) #f)])
      ))
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Having an `if` within a `cond` condition is usually a sign of doing something wrong. I think you meant to say this:

```
(define prefix
  (lambda (pf ls)
    (cond
      [(null? pf) #t]
      [(null? ls) #f]
      [(equal? (car pf) (car ls)) (prefix (cdr pf) (cdr ls))]
      [else #f])))
```

Comment: Well, that does indeed answer my question and solve the problem, thank you.